# How to send category id to ajax in shopware6 and display product according to this id?

Tags: ajax, fetch, product, categories, shopware

I want to display some product according to category using ajax.so how to send the category id to ajax in js and get in controller

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

The category ID is available server-side for example in the `\Shopware\Core\Content\Category\Event\NavigationLoadedEvent` via the navigation:

```
$navigation = $event->getNavigation();
$activeCategory = $navigation->getActive();
```

You can use this category and might not even need AJAX to display your product.

If you want to to it with AJAX, you have to get the category ID in the view.

To see what is already available in the view, use the code

```
{{ dump() }}
```

in your template.

By clicking through the tree printed by the `dump()` command you can find the node

```
page.header.navigation.active.id
```

so this will give you the ID which you can pass via AJAX to your controller.

You would usually create a JS component to execute the request, and pass in the above value.